# How to Location on without going to settings from within app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In Access user location, how to enable "Always" in App Location services in device settings without having to go to settings.

Comment: Have you requested always permission from the user? If so, and they have denied it or subsequently turned it off, then there is nothing you can do except ask them to turn it on

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to programatically toggle this setting without the user changing it manually in settings.

Comment: ok. any Option for go to settings->Location `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=Settings&path=Location"]]
` using Button.

Comment: Since ios6 (from memory) there is no uri to access settings aside from your own apps settings